# Lorentz Transformation and Special Relativity Equations

Tags: special-relativity

The fundamental equations by H. A. Lorentz are:

$x’ = (x – vt)*\gamma$

$t’ = (t – vx/c^2)*\gamma$

where, $\gamma$ is the Lorentz Factor $\gamma= 1/\sqrt{1 – v^2/c^2}$.

Let us consider a spaceship is just passing away from the earth at uniform $v = 0.05 \ c$ toward the Sun. Our goal is to transform $x$ and $t$ coordinates with reference to the spaceship’s frame of reference. Here, $x$ is the earth to sun distance which is about 150 million km or 500 light-second.

We find $\gamma = 1/0.999687 = 1.000313$ and at $t = 0$ when the ship is just passing the earth (considering it a point object), $x’ = 150.047941 \ 10^6 \mathrm{\ km}$. This increased distance is contradictory to the Special Relativity’s (SR) length contraction equation!

Now, consider an event (eg, explosion) that occurred on earth exactly when the ship passed the earth, that is, at $t = 0$. As per Lorentz, $t’ = -25 \mathrm{\ s}$ roughly. That means the ship would record the event as 25 s old at the very instant when it occurs!

The LT equations are apparently no good for coordinate transformation between the inertial frames of reference. Please correct me if I’m missing anything here.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve? If for example you want the length of the path from Earth to the Sun, it needs endpoints with equal $t^\prime$, not equal $t$.

Answer (score 2):

> Our goal is to transform x and t coordinates with reference to the spaceship’s frame of reference.

In addition to stating the goal of the transformation, it is important to be clear about the definition of the coordinate systems. In the usual coordinates used for such a problem we would put the earth at the spatial origin of the earth's coordinate system and the ship at the spatial origin of the ship's coordinate system. We would also align the spatial axes such that the $x$ axis and the $x'$ axis both point towards the sun which is also the direction of travel. The time origin for both coordinate systems is at the event when the ship passes the earth.

Now that the coordinate systems are clearly specified we can proceed with the rest of the problem.

> We find γ=1/0.999687=1.000313

For $v=0.05 \ c$ we have $\gamma = 1.00125$. It looks like you may have switched to $v=0.025 \ c$. I will stick with the stated $v=0.05 \ c$, but for future questions, $v=0.6 c$ is nice to use because $\gamma=1.25$ is a nice convenient fraction and you don't have to truncate anything.

> at $t=0$ when the ship is just passing the earth (considering it a point object), $x′=150.047941 \ 10^6 \mathrm{\ km}$. This increased distance is contradictory to the Special Relativity’s (SR) length contraction equation!

Yes, that contradiction is an indication that you have made a mistake. Specifically, we want the length in the ship's frame, so the important quantity is the $x'$ of the sun at $t'=0$, not at $t=0$.

So, in the earth's frame the sun has the worldline $s=(ct,x)$ which transforms to $s'=(c t', x')=(\gamma c t - \gamma v x/c, \gamma x - \gamma v t) $. Setting $t'=0$ and solving for $t$ we get $t=vx/c^2$ which gives us $s'=(0,x/\gamma)=(0,149.8 \ 10^6 \mathrm{\ km})$.

> Now, consider an event (eg, explosion) that occurred on earth exactly when the ship passed the earth, that is, at t=0. As per Lorentz, t′=−25 s roughly. That means the ship would record the event as 25 s old at the very instant when it occurs!

No, the origin of the unprimed frame transforms to the origin of the primed frame $o=(0,0)=o'$. Due to the relativity of simultaneity if an explosion occurs on the sun when the ship passes the earth in the earth's frame then in the ship's frame the explosion occurred about $25 \mathrm{\ s}$ earlier.

> The LT equations are apparently no good for coordinate transformation between the inertial frames of reference. Please correct me if I’m missing anything here.

Looks like you are just missing some practice. Keep working problems, and if you find a contradiction then go back and find where you made the mistake. The Lorentz transforms are valid and they do work, so if you find that they don't work then you know that you made a mistake in applying them.

Comment: Thanks very much. I learned LT ages (over 3 decades) ago and now revisiting again. I'll try re-understanding all these and come back with further questions if any. Sorry for the mistake in calculating Lorentz Factor.

Answer (score 0):

Lorentz transformations transform co-ordinates of events.

The first event you wanna transform is the one whose co-ordinates are $(x=150M km,t= 0s)$ in the Earth frame. This transforms to $(x'=150.04M km,  t'=\frac{-0.05 *150Mkm}{c}\gamma)$ in the spaceship frame.

Your mistake was to ignore the transformation of the time co-ordinate. The destination is $150.04Mkm$ away from the spaceship, but not at t'=0, but in the past.

The second event you wanna transform has co-ordinates $(0m,0s)$ in the Earth frame. This transforms to $(0,0)$ in the spaceship frame, as $x-vt=t-vx=0$ for $x=t=0$

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. I wanted to understand if someone on the ship will record the event (explosion) earlier than that recorded on the earth as t' is negative when t = 0. Also, I wonder what should the x' (sun's distance) be exactly when the ship passes the earth.

Comment: @FUA66 I think the answer by Dale addresses both of these points. 1.You have to find the $x'$ of the event which has $t'=0$. Dale's answer does this. That answer will agree with the length contraction formula. After all, that formula has been derived from the general Lorentz transformations. 2. If the explosion happened on Earth as your post says, then $t'$ isn't negative. $t'$ is 0. Maybe you instead meant that the explosion happened on Sun. Then yeah, for such an event $t$ is 0 but $t'$ is negative. That's just a feature of Lorentz transformations and it doesn't cause any inconsistencies

Comment: @FUA66 Why it doesn't cause any inconsistencies? It's better just to not hurt your head thinking about it. Just learn the geometric view of Lorentz transformations as the evil twin of rotations. Lorentz transformations are just a "rotation" of the spacetime co-ordinates, but with hyperbolic trig instead of usual trig functions. And start thinking of time as "just another co-ordinate". Time is just allowed to behave this way in relativity.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually, I am neither a physics teacher nor a student. So, I myself was somewhat unclear about my goal. As you both (including Dale) pointed out, the goal might be to determine the x and t coordinates of a distant event.

Comment: In the classical world of low velocity, x'= x - vt, t' = t. The LT equations must result in the same for v<<c. In such a case, the L Factor = 1. So, x' = x - vt. However, t' = t - vx/c2. Now, this fails to match the classical world even v is low when x is large compared with c.

Comment: Is my thinking clear and right this time? If yes, then the LT is no good as I said earlier. This is something I strongly believe after reviewing the fundamentals behind it. In my opinion, both the LT and Special Relativity equations are valid only for the thought experiments or similar for which they were derived. They are not universally applicable as we have been applying to. For example, c in those equations is not the universal speed of light but the speed of the light signal in the experiments. Please have a think and let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @FUA66 When you apply the limit $v<<c$, it means $\frac{vx}{c^2}$ tends to 0, as $\frac{v}{c}$ tends to 0 when v is far smaller than $c$. Hence $t'=t$ in the limit. I think you're learning relativity from the wrong, but unfortunately the most popular approach. Forget about all those flashlight experiments. Those books make it seem like "light" is at the center of relativity. Relativity isn't really about light. The $c$ is actually the universal speed limit which also happens to be the speed of light.

Comment: @FUA66 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations Look at the derivation using group theory section. Both Lorentz and Galilean transformations can be derived using four simple assumptions. That we end up with a universal speed limit is a consequence, not an assumption. Any massless particle must end up traveling at that speed. So light having that speed is also a consequence.

Comment: Thanks Rain Deer. Think if x is very large then vx/c2 does not tend to 0 anymore. BTW, my first learning of the LT and ST was long ago (over 3 decades) as an engineering student. Now, I'm revisiting them in a book by A. Einstein. I am wondering if the formulas translated/printed in this book can be wrong.

Comment: @FUA66 Doesn't matter how large you fix $x$ to be , it has to be a constant. The limit $\frac{v}{c}\rightarrow 0$ will always yield Galilean transformations. Galilean transformations *never* hold accurately in our universe anyway. They only approximately hold in the limit of tiny speeds. A universe in which Galilean transformations hold exactly will have $c=\infty$. In such a universe, $\frac{vx}{c^2}$ will be zero for all $v$.

Comment: @FUA66 The formulas in your book are totally correct. It's just that the approach makes it look like Lorentz transformation are a consequence of the constancy of speed of light. That can mislead one into believing that relativity is all about light. Technically, there's nothing wrong with that thinking. But you should really be viewing Lorentz transformations as the most fundamental, and the constancy of the speed of light as their consequence.